# What is this spiky fruit/cone?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I am trying to identify an unusual cone or fruit found today on Tayside in Scotland. Here is an image. Can you help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology!  Please insert images rather than making them links — this is for both the security and convenience of other users.  For details on how to use this site, please check out the tour: biology.stackexchange.com/tour and then the help pages on how to ask questions on this site: biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  Thanks! 

Comment: Sorry it won’t let me upload photos. Will try another website. Thanks anyway

Comment: What happened when you tried clicking on the image icon?  Assuming you have copies of the images you should be able to use the "Browse" option to upload copies of your images ...

Comment: You have to reduce the file size (by reducing quality). You can use any photo editor to do that. I'll do that for now. Please take care in future.